# Floating Point Algorithm when Divisor Mantissa is all zeros - say in the case of 2.0 in - IEEE -754

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

I have a need to implement a floating point package for small SBC and have most of the routines now working, but in the course of testing I have noticed that the algorithm in this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSuGM.jpg) (attachment) will not (indeed cannot) produce the correct answer in the case where the divisor mantissa is all zeros, for the example 500/2 will produce the answer 255.0 rather than 250.0

```
01000000011111110100000000000000 = 0x43FA00  (500 base 10) and
01000000000000000000000000000000 = 0x400000  (2 base 10)
```

will produce

```
01000011011111111000000000000000 =0x437F0 (255 base 10)
```

Is there anyone who has a good knowledge of Floating Point arithmetic or indeed FP algorithms that can help out please?

[[image: Floating Point Division Algorithm]]

Comment: I have edited the text to include all the zeros.   The example above is taken from an IEEE-7514 32 bit implementation, but the format I am using is an old Z80 BCD standard that uses 40 bits, but I don't think that is the issue, the problem appears to be the fact that the attached algorithm (with a zero mantissa) can only produce 1's in the quotient if the divisor is zero.  Regarding the exponent, the implementation I am working on uses a L-128 format for the exponent., e.g. 7000000000  84  15                (2^-1+2^-2+2^-3+2^-4)*2^4.

Comment: It's not clear from the image, but does "divisor" include the hidden leading bit?

Comment: I am wondering if that is the answer?

Comment: Thanks Paul and sorry for the delay - I had to take the family for a walk.  Anyway, yes what you do is first determine the resultant sign, then set the leading bits '1' and this gives  allows the algorithm to work.  You then assign the sign bit.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that IEEE-754 uses “significand” for the fraction portion of a floating-point number, not “mantissa,” and this is the preferred term. “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. A significand is linear (adding to it adds to the value represented) whereas a mantissa is logarithmic (adding to it multiplies the value represented).

Comment: Thanks Eric - this is very helpful and I just consulted my Knuth Vol 2 and he agrees with you and calls it an "abuse of terminology" - unfortunately the only other book I had (from which the algorithm was taken ) used the "manitissa" term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the chart shown says to work with the bits that are the primary **encoding** of the significand of a floating-point number. One should not confuse the bits that encode something with the thing itself. The actual significand of a normal IEEE-754 binary floating-point number, for example, is some binary numeral 1.xxx…xxx with a value in [1, 2) and a number of bits determined by the specific format. (Subnormal numbers use a numeral 0.xxx…xxx.) When the number is encoded in an interchange format, the xxx…xxx bits are stored in the primary significand field, and the leading 1 or 0 bit is encoded by way of the exponent field. (If the exponent field is not zero, and does not indicate an infinity or a NaN, then the leading bit is 1. Otherwise, it is 0.)

Generally, the actual significand is used for arithmetic, not just the bits of the primary significand field.